# bug with checked_out in Joomla

Tags: joomla, components, checkout

I have error when click to edit an item in Joomla admin:

> Error
>   Check-out failed with the following error: The user checking out does not match the user who checked out the item.

Actual result:

> It goes to the detail page and throws the error listed above.

Expected result:

> The list page is still displaying and it throws this error.

Answer (score 0):

Your user permissions will allow you to save as copy which is why you are allowed to open the article. You won't be allowed to save to the original item since you are not the user with it checked out.